# how to pass html string to another activity webView

Tags: java, android, html, webview

I want to pass html string to another activity webView.
Here my html string and Main_Activity Code. What is Another_Activity.java Code.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">String Passing</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    
    <string name="html_data">
 <![CDATA[
   <html>
     <head></head>
     <body style="text-align:justify;">
       <b><u>Everton plotting loan swoop for Man United youngster James Wilson</u></b>
       The Toffees were quick to register an early interest for the 19-year-old striker at the turn of the year.     
     Goodison Park boss Roberto Martinez has had his eye on a number of Old Trafford fringe players, although Wilson remains the most likely.
     Wilson, who scored twice for United last season, is also a target for West Bromwich Albion, having been recommended to them by former United midfielder Darren Fletcher.
     United will overhaul their striker department this summer following the release of Colombian striker Radamel Falcao and the continued uncertainty surrounding the future of Robin van Persie.
     United have made no decision yet on Wilson and boss Louis van Gaal will assess his pre-season before sitting down with the teenager and discussing all the options.
     </body>
   </html>
  ]]>
    </string>

    
    <string name="title_activity_another_">Another_Activity</string>
    
</resources>
```

Main_Activity.Java

```html
package com.nasir.stringpassing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 
 Button Nasir;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
  Nasir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Nasir);
  Nasir.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
//   String myString = getString(R.string.html_data); 
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second_Activity.class);
    intent.putExtra("header", getString(R.string.html_data));
    startActivity(intent);
   }
  });
  
 
 }

}
```

Please Write Another_Activity.Java code to show WebView text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create webview.xml in layout folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

then create Second_Activity like this.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class Second_Activity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String customHtml = getIntent()..getStringExtra("header");;
        webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");

    }

}
```

Comment: Please Solve my Problem  
Project Lick:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B46bPR7LKLjpZFRhcV9DdmIweTQ

When I search list item it's open other country details

Comment: Post question here and give me the link

Comment: When I search Brazil in Search box and click it's open Afghanistan

Comment: Please Solve this problem

Comment: If you really want your problem to be solved post here buddy

Comment: I think by now you would have posted question:)

Comment: Thanks, Now I am post my Problem. Please check it

Comment: My Question Link: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231558/when-i-search-listview-item-and-then-click-desire-item-it-does-open-first-posit

Comment: Project & Question Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231558/when-i-search-listview-item-and-then-click-desire-item-it-does-open-first-posit

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String myString = getIntent().getStringExtra("header");` in the second Activity, but if your html code is in string.xml, you just can get it as you do in the first activity - `String myString = getString(R.string.html_data);` and it will gives you the same.